# Can't get the first part of a text from a string using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've written a formula to get the first part of some text separated by space from a string located in cell A1. However, it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong with my formula? Thanks in advance.

This is the main string:

```
HOUSTON TX 77017-2328
```

The formula i've tried with:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)
```

The output I'm expecting:

```
HOUSTON
```

Comment: what is your output?

Comment: What are you getting instead?

Comment: You copied your data from a website that uses `&nbsp;` (*non-breaking space* or `CHAR(160)`) instead of regular spaces.

Comment: No problem with formula. Is it possible there is a leading space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a stylized space: char(160) versus char(32)

You can either replace all those with normal spaces or use this formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(160),A1)-1)
```

Comment: ... perhaps `IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(160), A1), FIND(CHAR(32), A1))-1`

Comment: Thanks Scott Craner, for your answer. It works great.

Answer (score 1):

To accommodate zip and zip+4 use,

```
=REPLACE(A1, LEN(A1)-IF(CODE(RIGHT(A1, 5))=45, 13, 8), LEN(A1), TEXT(,))
```

Assuming a two character state abbreviation.

[image]