# Can't subtract text of one cell from another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to subtract text of a cell from another text of different cell? I meant to subtract text in B1 from text in A1 using excel formula.

Cell A1 contains:

```
FRIENDSWOOD CITY N 77546-4005
```

Cell B1 contains:

```
77546-4005
```

I expect the result in C1 which can be obtained subtracting A1-B1 using formula:

```
FRIENDSWOOD CITY N
```

I tried like the below one but it gives me value error:

```
=A1-(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1)))
```

Comment: Virtual duplicate of [Can't get the first part of a text from a string using formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639463/cant-get-the-first-part-of-a-text-from-a-string-using-formula/45639733) from earlier today (as well as thousands of others). Perhaps you should sharpen your research skills.

Comment: @Jeeped ,This is not searching for the first part; rather, searching for the whole text except for the last portion.

Comment: The solutions still apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this formula:

```
=REPLACE(A1,FIND(B1,A1),LEN(B1),"")
```

Here's my result:

[image]

Comment: Won't that leave a trailing space?

Comment: @Jeeped I guess it would, but that's what the OP wanted. He can use `TRIM` pretty much easily if that's an issue. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this simple formula,

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,B1,"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gowtham Shiva, for your answer. Your one also works.